# Canonicalization of an XML document in PHP

Tags: php, xml, hash, canonicalization

I am trying to canonicalize an XML document in PHP.

Here is the XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://example.org/envelope">
  <Body>
    Olá mundo
  </Body>
</Envelope>
```

its an example from https://www.di-mgt.com.au/xmldsig2.html#twotypes.

the expected hash value is :

```
516b984d8ba0d7427593984a7e89f1b6182b011f
```

What I did in PHP :

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain');
$xml = new DOMDocument( "1.0", "utf-8" );
$string = '<Envelope xmlns="http://example.org/envelope">
<Body>
  Olá mundo
</Body>
</Envelope>'; 
$xml->loadXML($string);
$xml = $xml->C14N();
echo hash('sha1', $xml);
?>
```

however, the hash value is :

```
0ae2e4b4834d3a31447c50a3905669520be2bc73
```

Comment: I suspect you have encoding clashes. Your original XML states an encoding of ISO-8859-1 but your code states utf-8 (also if that is your raw PHP code then the file encoding will also matter)

Comment: Same `74a9f78abc46fe0328c8bb37d17ac01ca6c435f1` for me running PHP 8.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whitesapace it's important when doing C14N. XML sample is missing some of that in both the plain XML and PHP code.
Adding the missing withespace the sha1sum is correct

```
$string = '<Envelope xmlns="http://example.org/envelope">
  <Body>
    Olá mundo
  </Body>
  
</Envelope>';
```

Whitespace as shown on the provided URL

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://example.org/envelope">¶
♦♦<Body>¶
♦♦♦♦Olá mundo¶
♦♦</Body>¶
♦♦¶
</Envelope>
```

Comment: Can you please explain more ? I tried instead of copying and pasting in PHP, I wrote the XML part with spaces and new lines with no luck.

Comment: I got it once I wrote my comment :) Many thanks and much appreciated :)